Android Navigation Drawer Item Click Listener not working
Every time I click on the Navigation Drawer item, it closes and is not redirected to the intent activity. 
/* MainActivity.java */

NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

// Set a click listener for the Twitter menu item
MenuItem twitterMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.twitter_menu);
twitterMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle Twitter menu item click
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
});


navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.twitter_menu) {
            // Handle Twitter menu item click
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoActivity.class));
            // Return true to indicate that the item is handled
            return true;
        }


        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        // Return false to indicate that the item is not handled
        return false;
    }
});

This is my sidemenu.xml that is inside menu resource directory
/*sidemenu.xml*/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Rewards">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share_menu"
                android:title="Earn Rewards"
                android:icon="@drawable/share_vector" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/refer_menu"
                android:title="Redeem your Points"
                android:icon="@drawable/refer_vector" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group android:id="@+id/social_group">
        <item
            android:title="Follow Us on Social Media">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_menu"
                    android:title="Linkedin"
                    android:icon="@drawable/youtube_color_svgrepo_com" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_menu"
                    android:title="X"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xlog"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/facebook_menu"
                    android:title="Facebook"
                    android:icon="@drawable/facebook_color_svgrepo_com" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/whatsapp_menu"
                    android:title="WhatsApp"
                    android:icon="@drawable/whatsapp_svgrepo_com" />

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>

/* activity_main.xml */

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!--Sidemenu-->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerfile"
        app:menu="@menu/sidemenu" />
    <!--My ScrollView Con-->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:title="CAMPUS"
                app:titleMarginStart="40dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleText">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bell_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Bell Icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/wallet" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

I have tried all the possible ways. I knew that every time the navigation drawer item clicked, it closed the drawer layout and nothing happened. 

lots of things may gone wrong here, first of all, put a breakpoint in the onMenuItemClick method body to see if that's being called when you click on the menu item, alternatively, you can put some Logs in it to check that, then you can check the id of the clicked menu item, maybe that's another id that's being called, as I can see you havedrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  in the onMenuItemClick method and there is a possibility that this part is not false if (id == R.id.twitter_menu) { and it ended up only closing the drawer
